# Understanding why php increments characters the way it does

Tags: php, character, arithmetic-expressions

PHP Manual states:
PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. 
For example, in PHP and Perl `$a = 'Z'; $a++;` turns $a into 'AA', 
while in C `a = 'Z'; a++;` turns a into '[' 
(ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91).

If PHP converts the characters to ascii values (assuming) when dealing with arithmetic operations on characters, should it not print '[' instead of AA? Why and how does PHP increment characters the way it does?

Comment: Why?, because thats the way they chose it do it. How?, read the source.

Comment: Oh, and its basically base 26 counting.

Comment: At it says, it follows Perl's conventions. That means it does *not* treat characters by their ASCII value. The way it works is not a byproduct of some weird quirk, it's a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If PHP converts the characters to ascii values (assuming) when dealing with arithmetic operations on characters ...

Your assumption is false, since it treats `"0"` and `0` as equal, instead of `"0"` and `48`.

```
$ php
<?php
echo "0" == 0 ; echo "\n";
echo "0" == 48 ; echo "\n";
1
​
```